# Template_searchpath gives TemplateNotFound error in Airflow and cannot find the SQL script

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG described like this :

```
tmpl_search_path = '/home/airflow/gcs/sql_requests/'

with DAG(dag_id='pipeline', default_args=default_args, template_searchpath = [tmpl_search_path]) as dag:

    create_table = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id = 'create_table',
        sql = 'create_table.sql',
        use_legacy_sql = False,
        destination_dataset_table = some_table)
    )
```

The task `create_table` calls a SQL script `create_table.sql`. This SQL script is not in the same folder as the DAG folder : it is in a `sql_requests` folder at the same level as the DAG folder.
This is the architecture inside the bucket of the GCP Composer (which is the Google Airflow) is :

```
bucket_name
|- airflow.cfg
|- dags
   |_ pipeline.py
|- ...
|_ sql_requests
   |_ create_table.sql
```

What path do I need to set for template_searchpath to reference the folder `sql_requests` inside the Airflow bucket on GCP ?

I have tried `template_searchpath= ['/home/airflow/gcs/sql_requests']`, `template_searchpath= ['../sql_requests']`, `template_searchpath= ['/sql_requests']` but none of these have worked.

The error message I get is 'jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage it is not possible to store files that are needed to execute dags elsewhere than in the folders `dags` or `plugins` :

> To avoid a workflow failure, store your DAGs, plugins, and Python modules in the dags/ or plugins/ folders—even if your Python modules do not contain DAGs or plugins.

This is the reason why I had the TemplateNotFound error.

Answer (score 2):

You can store in mounted/known paths which are dags/plugins OR data

data folder has no capacity limits but it's easy to throw yourself off using it to store anything that the web server would need to read, because the web server can't access that folder (e.g if you put SQL files in /data folder,  you would not be able to parse rendered template in the UI, but any tasks that need to access the file during run time would just run fine)

Answer (score 2):

Change '**sql_requests**' folder into the '**dag**' folder so that your code will be like this:

```
tmpl_search_path = '/home/airflow/dags/sql_requests/'  
with DAG(dag_id='pipeline', default_args=default_args, template_searchpath = [tmpl_search_path]) as dag:      
    create_table = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id = 'create_table',
        sql = 'create_table.sql',
        use_legacy_sql = False,
        destination_dataset_table = some_table
    )
)
```

For me, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I believe by default the operator looks for sql files in the DAG folder, so you could put your SQL into the folder

```
gs://composer-bucket-name/dags/sql/create_table.sql
```

And then reference it as

```
sql = '/sql/create_table.sql'
```

If that doesn't work, try it without the leading `/` (which I'm not sure you need)

**Edit**

If you want to put them in a folder at the root of the bucket, try

```
sql = '../sql/create_table.sql'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done this and it worked. But I would like to know if this is possible to put my sql requests in a folder other than in the dag folder, like `gs://composer-bucket-name/sql/create_table.sql`. I tried to follow the same pattern but it did not work and I have no idea why.

Comment: Thank for your update, but unfortunately I tried and it did not work, I don't know why